# How to change options of mmenu after I have created

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

My mmenu was created by these code.

```
$("#slideMenu").mmenu({
    position: 'right',
    classes: 'mm-light',
    dragOpen: true
});
```

When a user do something... I need to disallow drag by set `dragOpen = false` but I don't know how to do that.

Someone please help me. Thanks.

Comment: you are include the js-jQuery.hammer.js ?

Comment: So, is this still not possible almost 5 years later...?